# Phone (usually) reboots when train enters a specific tunnel

Tags: reboot

The title is pretty much it.

There's a tunnel that, when I'm in a train entering or exiting it, frequently reboots my phone.

It's quite rare for me to see spontaneous reboots otherwise.

Why would such a thing happen?

Comment: +1. Interesting. Is your data / GPS on before this happens? When you enter /exit a tunnel state of two things will change - Mobile data and GPS. My wild, wild guess is that one of your installed apps is not able to handle that gracefully and instead trigger reboot . You could check this by seeing which apps use this features by checking their permissions (plenty of apps on Play Store that do that (aSpotCat for example). Disable those apps from settings and see if it happens again. If it doesn't, then likely one of those is the culprit. How to identify culprit app is, well, another question

Comment: @beeshyams: Interesting. GPS is off but data might be on every time this happens. Thanks for the tips, I'll let you know if I find something.